# Javascript - Filter Div Rows with Text Field, but also need to HIDE other classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of javascript that uses a simple text field to "hide" certain rows from a table.  At the moment any div.contentrow in the #shopTbl will be CHECKED to see if it matches the string in the text field. (You can see an example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/jabbamonkey/pen/poPXJWR ).  I'd like to add some additional functionality to the form, but am having trouble with it (since I don't know javascript very well)...

If a single character is typed, I'd LIKE to hide two other classes (.rowSec and .rowCat). These are section/category title "rows" that I want to disappear when the "results" are filtered. But, I want them to reappear when the text field doesn't have any characters (is empty).

Here is what I have so far... This works to filter, but doesn't get rid of the .rowSec and .rowCat divs

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.search').on('keyup',function(){
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#shopTbl div.contentrow').each(function(){
      var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".descexpand").hide();
      }else{
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.rowSec, .rowCat {
  background-color:#999;
  }
input { 
  margin:5px; 
  height:30px; 
  font-size:16px; 
  }
.flextable { 
  width:400px; 
  }
.flexrow { 
  padding:3px; 
  border-top:1px solid #333
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Filter Form -->
<div class="tablefilter">
  <div class="dmtabform">
    <div class="dmtabinput">
      <input type="text" class="search form-control input-txt" placeholder="Filter Content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="shoptable flextable" id="shopTbl" >
  <div class="row1 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      First One
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Second Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3 flexrow rowCat contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Category Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Forth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Fifth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow rowSec contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Section Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Seventh Row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's work as usual, I still don't understand what you want to do. I don't find  `.descexpand` class used in your HTML. Can you provide more details , desire out put .

Comment: The descexpand relates to another part of the code ... but that little clue just helped me solve this.... I just need to add                     $(".rowCat").hide();
                    $(".rowSec").hide(); to the code. Thanks!!!!   :)

Comment: `$(".rowCat, .rowSec").hide()` also works

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... Just add

```
  $(".rowCat").hide();
  $(".rowSec").hide();
```

to the javascript...

Answer (score 0):

On your CodePen, you have the same class `.contentrow` on the rows with the classes `.rowCat` and `.rowSec`. So you need to eliminate them in the jQuery selector with `:not()` like this:

```
$('#shopTbl div.contentrow:not(.rowCat):not(.rowSec)')
```

Otherwise they will be they will be included in the text evaluation because they are included in the nodes selected. So they could be unhidden if they contain any text in the search.

See snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search').on('keyup', function() {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    
    //Hide if any value in the search box, otherwise show
    searchTerm.length > 0 ? $(".rowCat, .rowSec").hide() : $(".rowCat, .rowSec").show();
    
    $('#shopTbl div.contentrow:not(.rowCat):not(.rowSec)').each(function() {
      var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if (lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.rowSec,
.rowCat {
  background-color: #999;
}

input {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.flextable {
  width: 400px;
}

.flexrow {
  padding: 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Filter Form -->
<div class="tablefilter">
  <div class="dmtabform">
    <div class="dmtabinput">
      <input type="text" class="search form-control input-txt" placeholder="Filter Content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="shoptable flextable" id="shopTbl">
  <div class="row1 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      First One
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Second Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3 flexrow rowCat contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Category Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Forth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Fifth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow rowSec contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Section Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Seventh Row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the addition condition like the text should not be `Category Row` and `Section Row` and when the search text is empty then it should show the rows. I have updated the following lines of code\

```
 var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
 if((lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1 || lineStr == 'category row' || lineStr == 'section row') && searchTerm != ''){
```

In the first line I used `trim` method to remove the unwanted spaces if any. Because we need to compare this text exactly with `category row` and `section row`. Second line I have added condition to hide the result if it matching `category row` and `section row` and also it should not have the empty search string.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.search').on('keyup',function(){
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#shopTbl div.contentrow').each(function(){
      var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
      if((lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1 || lineStr == 'category row' || lineStr == 'section row') && searchTerm != ''){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".descexpand").hide();
      }else{
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.rowSec, .rowCat {
  background-color:#999;
  }
input { 
  margin:5px; 
  height:30px; 
  font-size:16px; 
  }
.flextable { 
  width:400px; 
  }
.flexrow { 
  padding:3px; 
  border-top:1px solid #333
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Filter Form -->
<div class="tablefilter">
  <div class="dmtabform">
    <div class="dmtabinput">
      <input type="text" class="search form-control input-txt" placeholder="Filter Content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="shoptable flextable" id="shopTbl" >
  <div class="row1 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      First One
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Second Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3 flexrow rowCat contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Category Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Forth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Fifth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow rowSec contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Section Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Seventh Row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

> PS: prefer to use input event, has he works also with mouse right click events (cut/past/copy)

```js
const 
  SearchFilter  = document.querySelector('input.search')
, contentRows   = document.querySelectorAll('.contentrow')
, hideRowsInput = document.querySelectorAll('.contentrow.rowSec, .contentrow.rowCat')
  ;
SearchFilter.oninput = e =>
  {  
  let sFilter = SearchFilter.value.trim().toLowerCase()

  contentRows.forEach( x =>
    {
    let hasStr = x.innerText.toLowerCase().includes( sFilter )
    x.classList.toggle('noDisplay', !hasStr )
    })

  if (sFilter !== '')
    hideRowsInput.forEach( x => x.classList.add('noDisplay'))
  }
```

```css
.rowSec , 
.rowCat {
  background : #999;
  }
input { 
  margin    : 5px; 
  height    : 30px; 
  font-size : 16px; 
  }
.flextable { 
  width     : 400px; 
  }
.flexrow { 
  padding    : 3px; 
  border-top : 1px solid #333
  }
.noDisplay {
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Filter Form -->
<div class="tablefilter">
  <div class="dmtabform">
    <div class="dmtabinput">
      <input type="text" class="search form-control input-txt" placeholder="Filter Content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="shoptable flextable" id="shopTbl" >
  <div class="row1 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      First One
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Second Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3 flexrow rowCat contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Category Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Forth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Fifth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4 flexrow rowSec contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Section Row
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5 flexrow contentrow">
    <div class="col1 flexcol ">
      Seventh Row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```